# Setting background of panel with custom color code

Tags: wpf, brushes, color-codes

In WPF,I can set the background of a stack panel using the below code

```
stackPanelFlasher.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
```

How  can I set the color as a hex color code for example `#C7DFFC`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
stackPanelFlasher.Background=  (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#C7DFFC");
```

Should do the job. If you want to make it waterproof, better would be

```
BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();  
Brush brush=(Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#C7DFFC"); 
brush.Freeze();
stackPanelFlasher.Background=brush;
```

needs fewer resources...

Answer (score 14):

```
stackPanelFlasher.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue));
```

Answer (score 11):

I think this sample helps you for xaml solution;

```
 <Border.Background>
       <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1.204,0.5" StartPoint="0.056,0.5">
           <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
           <GradientStop Color="#FFD4D7DB" Offset="1" />
       </LinearGradientBrush>                     
  </Border.Background>
```

Answer (score 4):

The following oneliner should work.

```
something.Background = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#C7DFFC");
```